# Javascript: Make cash register themed website and calculate the total from the given items

Tags: javascript, console.log

this is my first time posting so if I broke any rules forgive me. I know there are some answers about Cash Register but my assignment was to make cash register themed website where I use the prompt to order and a total is given on the web page. I have gotten this code to calculate the subtotal but I cannot figure why the total is not being calculated and one more thing How do I get the document.write to give the total when using console.log. Please Help. Thank You.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Please Make this Work!</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <script>
    var items = ["Bananas", "Kiwis", "Apples", "Pears", "Orange"];
    var numItems = new Array();
     for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
     numItems.push(prompt("How Many " +items[i] +" do you want?"));
     console.log(numItems);
    }
   var $items= [3, 4, 3.5, 1, 0.75];

   for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var itemTotal=new Array();
    itemTotal= ($items[i]*numItems[i]);
        console.log(itemTotal);
    for (it=0; i<itemTotal.length; it++) {
    var x = itemTotal[it];
    var total = x + itemTotal[it];
    console.log(total);
        }
  }
  document.write(total);
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some logical flaws in your script. Be careful about what should be in a for-loop and what needs to be executed after a certain loop. Although you need to check variable-types, for example `var a = 12 + "2"` will become `a = "122"`. Use `parseInt (var)` to parse the numbers typed into the prompt. To increment a variable do `var a = 0; var a += 2`. After that `var a` will be `2`.

I fixed your code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Please Make this Work!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var items = ["Bananas", "Kiwis", "Apples", "Pears", "Orange"];
            var numItems = new Array();
            for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                numItems.push(prompt("How Many " +items[i] +" do you want?"));
                console.log(numItems);
            }
            var $items= [3, 4, 3.5, 1, 0.75];

            var itemTotal=new Array();
            for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                itemTotal.push ($items[i]*parseInt(numItems[i]));
                console.log(itemTotal);
            }

            var total = 0;
            for (j=0; j<itemTotal.length; j++) {
                total += itemTotal[j];
                console.log(total);
            }
            document.write(total);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to give my thanks but the comment box says to avoid it? So I will say that today is my first time learning about parseInt. Is there a place I can learn and master javascript? Im using Khan Academy and w3schools. Im going to start using codeacademy.

Comment: No thanks needed. We all started small and got bigger by help from others. But you could mark my answer as accepted. Best practice to get better is just writing code and figure out how to solve problems you encounter.